# There is a difference between malware detection using automata and family behavior graph?

Tags: malware, automation, anomaly-detection

Is there a difference between dynamic malware detection using automata and family behavior - graph?

I think that they are both relying on API function calls but I don't understand if there is any major difference between them.

If you're not sure what I'm talking about:

automata - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309710040_Detecting_Malicious_Behaviors_of_Software_through_Analysis_of_API_Sequence_k-grams

family behavior - graph - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dOZ80FcaBiDHRDW4kusdxXGZw2C9aXfK

first one - just click on Request full-text and it will download the pdf files. the second one is google drive link.